# I Need to show bootstrap modal when i click on calendar cell (dncalendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need help how to show modal when i click on calendar cell, im using [dncalendar](https://github.com/black-lotus/dnCalendar).
i want if u just click on the cell the modal open & shows the event date on time..
[this is my design for the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q4SU.jpg)

```js
(function(a){a.fn.dnCalendar=function(n){var l=a(this);var b={};var d=new Date();var i=null;var f=new Date();var e=function(q,s){var r=new Date(q,s-1,1);var o=new Date(q,s,0);var p=r.getDay()+o.getDate();return Math.ceil(p/7)};var h=function(){var Z=d.getMonth();var ag=d.getDate();var T=d.getFullYear();var J=b.monthNames[Z];if(b.monthUseShortName==true){J=b.monthNamesShort[Z]}var X=a("<div id='dncalendar-header' class='dncalendar-header'></div>");X.append("<h2>"+J+" "+T+"</h2>");var v=false;var r=null;if(typeof b.minDate!=="undefined"){var aj=b.minDate.split("-");r=new Date(aj[0],aj[1]-1,aj[2]);if(r.getFullYear()>=T){if(r.getMonth()>=Z){v=true}}}var M=false;var A=null;if(typeof b.maxDate!=="undefined"){var F=b.maxDate.split("-");A=new Date(F[0],F[1]-1,F[2]);if(A.getFullYear()<=T){if(A.getMonth()<=Z){M=true}}}var Q=a("<div id='dncalendar-links' class='dncalendar-links'></div>");var W=a("<div id='dncalendar-prev-month' class='dncalendar-prev-month'></div>");var B=a("<div id='dncalendar-next-month' class='dncalendar-next-month'></div>");if(v){W.addClass("dncalendar-inactive");W.removeAttr("id")}if(M){B.addClass("dncalendar-inactive");B.removeAttr("id")}Q.append(W);Q.append(B);X.append(Q);var C=a("<div id='dncalendar-body' class='dncalendar-body'></div>");var P=a("<table></table>");var N=b.dayNames;if(b.dayUseShortName==true){N=b.dayNamesShort}var q=a("<thead></thead>");var p=a("<tr></tr>");var af=N.length;for(var ad=0;ad<af;ad++){p.append("<td "+((ad==0||ad==af-1)?'class="holiday"':"")+">"+N[ad]+"</td>")}q.append(p);var u=a("<tbody></tbody>");var x=e(T,Z+1);var E=7;var t=1;var o=new Date(T,Z,1);var ah=new Date(T,Z+1,0);var O=new Date(T,Z,0);var R=O.getDate()-o.getDay()+1;var s=new Date(T,Z+1,1);var Y=s.getDate();var K=0;if(r!=null){K=r.getDate()}var S=0;if(A!=null){S=A.getDate()}var z="today";var ac="default date";if(typeof b.dataTitles!=="undefined"){if(typeof b.dataTitles.defaultDate!=="undefined"){ac=b.dataTitles.defaultDate}if(typeof b.dataTitles.today!=="undefined"){z=b.dataTitles.today}}for(var ad=0;ad<x;ad++){var V=a("<tr></tr>");for(var ab=0;ab<E;ab++){if((ad!=0&&ad!=x-1)||(ad==0&&ab>=o.getDay())||(ad==x-1&&ab<=ah.getDay())){var w="";var H="";if(f.getFullYear()==T&&f.getMonth()==Z&&f.getDate()==t){w=" today-date ";H="data-title='"+z+"'"}if(i!=null&&i.getFullYear()==T&&i.getMonth()==Z&&i.getDate()==t){w=" default-date ";H="data-title='"+ac+"'"}if(ab==0||ab==E-1){w+=" holiday "}if(typeof b.notes!=="undefined"){if(k(new Date(T,Z,t))){w+=" note "}}var U="<td id='calendarClick' class='"+w+" calendarClick' data-date='"+t+"' data-month='"+(Z+1)+"' data-year='"+T+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+t+"</div></td>";if(r!=null){if(r.getFullYear()>=T){if(r.getMonth()>=Z&&t<K){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+t+"' data-month='"+(Z+1)+"' data-year='"+T+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+t+"</div></td>"}}}if(A!=null){if(A.getFullYear()<=T){if(A.getMonth()<=Z&&t>S){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+t+"' data-month='"+(Z+1)+"' data-year='"+T+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+t+"</div></td>"}}}V.append(U);t++}else{if(ad==0){var w="";var H="";if(f.getFullYear()==O.getFullYear()&&f.getMonth()==O.getMonth()&&f.getDate()==R){w=" today-date ";H="data-title='"+z+"'"}if(i!=null&&i.getFullYear()==O.getFullYear()&&i.getMonth()==O.getMonth()&&i.getDate()==R){w=" default-date ";H="data-title='"+ac+"'"}if(ab==0||ab==E-1){w+=" holiday "}if(typeof b.notes!=="undefined"){if(k(new Date(O.getFullYear(),O.getMonth(),R))){w+=" note "}}var U="<td id='calendarClick' class='"+w+"' data-date='"+R+"' data-month='"+(O.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+O.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+R+"</div></td>";if(r!=null){if(r.getFullYear()>O.getFullYear()){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+R+"' data-month='"+(O.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+O.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+R+"</div></td>"}else{if(r.getFullYear()==O.getFullYear()&&r.getMonth()>O.getMonth()){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+R+"' data-month='"+(O.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+O.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+R+"</div></td>"}}}V.append(U);R++}if(ad==x-1){var w="";var H="";if(f.getFullYear()==s.getFullYear()&&f.getMonth()==s.getMonth()&&f.getDate()==Y){w=" today-date ";H="data-title='"+z+"'"}if(i!=null&&i.getFullYear()==s.getFullYear()&&i.getMonth()==s.getMonth()&&i.getDate()==Y){w=" default-date ";H="data-title='"+ac+"'"}if(ab==0||ab==E-1){w+=" holiday "}if(typeof b.notes!=="undefined"){if(k(new Date(s.getFullYear(),s.getMonth(),Y))){w+=" note "}}var U="<td id='calendarClick' class='"+w+"' data-date='"+Y+"' data-month='"+(s.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+s.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+Y+"</div></td>";if(A!=null){if(A.getFullYear()<=s.getFullYear()){if(A.getMonth()<=s.getMonth()){if(A.getMonth()<s.getMonth()){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+Y+"' data-month='"+(s.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+s.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+Y+"</div></td>"}else{if(S<Y){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+Y+"' data-month='"+(s.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+s.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+Y+"</div></td>"}}}}}V.append(U);Y++}}}u.append(V)}var ai="";if(b.showNotes){var aa=m();var L=aa.length;if(L>0){ai=a("<ul class='dncalendar-note-list'></ul>");for(var ad=0;ad<L;ad++){var ae=aa[ad].date;var G=aa[ad].notes;var D=G.length;var I="";I+="<li class='date'>";I+="<span>"+ae+"</span> ";if(D>0){I+=" : ";for(var ab=0;ab<D;ab++){I+=G[ab];if(D<=ab){I+=", "}}}I+="</li>";ai.append(I)}}}P.append(q);P.append(u);C.append(P);l.html("");l.append(X);l.append(C);l.append(ai)};var k=function(p){var s=b.notes.length;for(var r=0;r<s;r++){var q=b.notes[r].date.split("-");var o=new Date(q[0],q[1]-1,q[2]);if(o.getFullYear()==p.getFullYear()&&o.getMonth()==p.getMonth()&&o.getDate()==p.getDate()){return true}}return false};var m=function(){var p=[];var t=b.notes.length;for(var s=0;s<t;s++){var r=b.notes[s].date.split("-");var o=new Date(r[0],r[1]-1,r[2]);if(o.getFullYear()==d.getFullYear()&&o.getMonth()==d.getMonth()){var q={};q.date=o.getDate();q.notes=b.notes[s].note;p.push(q)}}return p};var g=function(){var o=new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,1);var p=o.getDate();var r=o.getMonth();var q=o.getFullYear();d=new Date(q,r,p);h()};var c=function(){var q=new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()-1,1);var o=q.getDate();var r=q.getMonth();var p=q.getFullYear();d=new Date(p,r,o);h()};var j=function(){a("body").on("click","#calendarClick",function(){var o=a(this).data("date");var p=a(this).data("month");var q=a(this).data("year");b.dayClick.call(this,new Date(q,p-1,o),l)});a("body").on("click","#dncalendar-prev-month",function(){c()});a("body").on("click","#dncalendar-next-month",function(){g()})};return{build:function(){b=a.extend({},a.fn.dnCalendar.defaults,n);if(typeof b.defaultDate!=="undefined"){var o=b.defaultDate.split("-");d=new Date(o[0],o[1]-1,o[2]);i=d}h();j()},update:function(p){b=a.extend(b,p);if(typeof b.defaultDate!=="undefined"){var o=b.defaultDate.split("-");d=new Date(o[0],o[1]-1,o[2]);i=d}h()}}};a.fn.dnCalendar.defaults={monthNames:["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],monthNamesShort:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Agu","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dec"],dayNames:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],dayNamesShort:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],dayUseShortName:false,monthUseShortName:false,showNotes:false,dayClick:function(c,b){}}}(jQuery));
```

```css
.dncalendar-inactive{opacity:.2}.dncalendar-header{margin:20px 0;position:relative}.dncalendar-header h2{color:#fa8a20;font-size:20px;line-height:1;text-align:center}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links{height:19px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:2px}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links div{cursor:pointer;width:35px;height:35px;-webkit-user-select:none;touch-action:pan-y;-webkit-user-drag:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links .dncalendar-next-month{position:absolute;right:-6px;background:url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat -111px 0;background-size:148px 31px}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links .dncalendar-prev-month{position:absolute;left:10px;background:url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;background-size:148px 31px}.dncalendar-body{margin:0 0 10px}.dncalendar-body table{width:100%;text-align:center;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:15px}.dncalendar-body table th,td{display:table-cell;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}.dncalendar-body thead td{color:#727272;font-size:11px;text-transform:uppercase;padding:10px 0}.dncalendar-body tbody tr td{width:13%;border-top:1px solid #ddd;color:#bdbdbd;background:#f8f8f8;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:middle}.dncalendar-body tbody td#calendarClick{cursor:pointer}.dncalendar-body tbody td.calendarClick{color:#434343;background:#fff}.dncalendar-body tbody td .entry{padding:11px 0 13px;position:relative}.dncalendar-body tbody td.calendarClick:active{background:#ddd}.dncalendar-body tbody td .entry:after{content:attr(data-title);left:0;position:absolute;font-size:10px;bottom:1px;text-align:center;width:100%}.dncalendar-body table td.holiday{color:#fa8a20 !important}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.holiday{color:#fa8a20 !important}.dncalendar-body table td.default-date{border:1px solid #eee;color:#fff !important;background:#fa8a20}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.default-date{border:1px solid #ddd;color:#fff !important;background:#fa8a20}.dncalendar-body table td.today-date{border:1px solid #7ee699;color:#7ee699 !important;background:#e9fdee}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.today-date{border:1px solid rgba(100%,100%,100%,0.0);color:#fa8a20 !important;background:#ffecd9}.dncalendar-body table td.note,.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.note{position:relative}.dncalendar-body table td.note:before{display:block;position:absolute;width:0;height:0;top:0;right:0;content:"";border-top:5px solid #c55;border-right:5px solid #c55;border-left:5px solid transparent;border-bottom:5px solid transparent}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.note:before{display:block;position:absolute;width:0;height:0;top:0;right:0;content:"";border-top:5px solid #d00;border-right:5px solid #d00;border-left:5px solid transparent;border-bottom:5px solid transparent}.dncalendar-note-list{list-style:none;margin-left:4.5%;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;color:#999}.dncalendar-note-list .date{color:#d00}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dncalendar-skin.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!---Calendar here --->

<div id="dncalendar-container">
</div>
<!---End Calendar --->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var my_calendar = $("#dncalendar-container").dnCalendar({
                dataTitles: { defaultDate: 'default', today : 'Today' },
                notes: [
                  { "date": "2016-02-25", "note": ["date here"] },
                  { "date": "2016-02-28", "note": ["date here"] }
                  ],
                showNotes: true,
                dayClick: function(date, view) {
                 alert(date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear());
                }
   });

   // init calendar
   my_calendar.build();

   // update calendar
   my_calendar.update({
    minDate: "2016-02-23",
    defaultDate: new Date()
   });
  });
  </script>
```

thank you

Comment: add code to your question or you're going to be downvoted into oblivion

Comment: thank you, i already did, can u check please

Comment: Do you need help only with writing bootstrap modal, or do you want to show the note's text also there?

Comment: Well, its an event calender, i want it to show the schedule for each day on modal when u click on the calendar cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go;

Add Modal HTML Markup

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changed only in following JS

```
dayClick: function(date, view) {
var selecteddate = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    $('#myModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-body').html(selecteddate);
    });
}
```

1. Added `selecteddate` as variable for current date
2. on click calendar date, modal will show via JavaScript `$('#myModal').modal('show')`
3. Use modal `shown.bs.modal` event and pass the `var selecteddate` value to `$('.modal-body')` when modal shown.

Same way, can pass any other information along side with calendar date.

```js
(function(a){a.fn.dnCalendar=function(n){var l=a(this);var b={};var d=new Date();var i=null;var f=new Date();var e=function(q,s){var r=new Date(q,s-1,1);var o=new Date(q,s,0);var p=r.getDay()+o.getDate();return Math.ceil(p/7)};var h=function(){var Z=d.getMonth();var ag=d.getDate();var T=d.getFullYear();var J=b.monthNames[Z];if(b.monthUseShortName==true){J=b.monthNamesShort[Z]}var X=a("<div id='dncalendar-header' class='dncalendar-header'></div>");X.append("<h2>"+J+" "+T+"</h2>");var v=false;var r=null;if(typeof b.minDate!=="undefined"){var aj=b.minDate.split("-");r=new Date(aj[0],aj[1]-1,aj[2]);if(r.getFullYear()>=T){if(r.getMonth()>=Z){v=true}}}var M=false;var A=null;if(typeof b.maxDate!=="undefined"){var F=b.maxDate.split("-");A=new Date(F[0],F[1]-1,F[2]);if(A.getFullYear()<=T){if(A.getMonth()<=Z){M=true}}}var Q=a("<div id='dncalendar-links' class='dncalendar-links'></div>");var W=a("<div id='dncalendar-prev-month' class='dncalendar-prev-month'></div>");var B=a("<div id='dncalendar-next-month' class='dncalendar-next-month'></div>");if(v){W.addClass("dncalendar-inactive");W.removeAttr("id")}if(M){B.addClass("dncalendar-inactive");B.removeAttr("id")}Q.append(W);Q.append(B);X.append(Q);var C=a("<div id='dncalendar-body' class='dncalendar-body'></div>");var P=a("<table></table>");var N=b.dayNames;if(b.dayUseShortName==true){N=b.dayNamesShort}var q=a("<thead></thead>");var p=a("<tr></tr>");var af=N.length;for(var ad=0;ad<af;ad++){p.append("<td "+((ad==0||ad==af-1)?'class="holiday"':"")+">"+N[ad]+"</td>")}q.append(p);var u=a("<tbody></tbody>");var x=e(T,Z+1);var E=7;var t=1;var o=new Date(T,Z,1);var ah=new Date(T,Z+1,0);var O=new Date(T,Z,0);var R=O.getDate()-o.getDay()+1;var s=new Date(T,Z+1,1);var Y=s.getDate();var K=0;if(r!=null){K=r.getDate()}var S=0;if(A!=null){S=A.getDate()}var z="today";var ac="default date";if(typeof b.dataTitles!=="undefined"){if(typeof b.dataTitles.defaultDate!=="undefined"){ac=b.dataTitles.defaultDate}if(typeof b.dataTitles.today!=="undefined"){z=b.dataTitles.today}}for(var ad=0;ad<x;ad++){var V=a("<tr></tr>");for(var ab=0;ab<E;ab++){if((ad!=0&&ad!=x-1)||(ad==0&&ab>=o.getDay())||(ad==x-1&&ab<=ah.getDay())){var w="";var H="";if(f.getFullYear()==T&&f.getMonth()==Z&&f.getDate()==t){w=" today-date ";H="data-title='"+z+"'"}if(i!=null&&i.getFullYear()==T&&i.getMonth()==Z&&i.getDate()==t){w=" default-date ";H="data-title='"+ac+"'"}if(ab==0||ab==E-1){w+=" holiday "}if(typeof b.notes!=="undefined"){if(k(new Date(T,Z,t))){w+=" note "}}var U="<td id='calendarClick' class='"+w+" calendarClick' data-date='"+t+"' data-month='"+(Z+1)+"' data-year='"+T+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+t+"</div></td>";if(r!=null){if(r.getFullYear()>=T){if(r.getMonth()>=Z&&t<K){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+t+"' data-month='"+(Z+1)+"' data-year='"+T+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+t+"</div></td>"}}}if(A!=null){if(A.getFullYear()<=T){if(A.getMonth()<=Z&&t>S){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+t+"' data-month='"+(Z+1)+"' data-year='"+T+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+t+"</div></td>"}}}V.append(U);t++}else{if(ad==0){var w="";var H="";if(f.getFullYear()==O.getFullYear()&&f.getMonth()==O.getMonth()&&f.getDate()==R){w=" today-date ";H="data-title='"+z+"'"}if(i!=null&&i.getFullYear()==O.getFullYear()&&i.getMonth()==O.getMonth()&&i.getDate()==R){w=" default-date ";H="data-title='"+ac+"'"}if(ab==0||ab==E-1){w+=" holiday "}if(typeof b.notes!=="undefined"){if(k(new Date(O.getFullYear(),O.getMonth(),R))){w+=" note "}}var U="<td id='calendarClick' class='"+w+"' data-date='"+R+"' data-month='"+(O.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+O.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+R+"</div></td>";if(r!=null){if(r.getFullYear()>O.getFullYear()){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+R+"' data-month='"+(O.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+O.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+R+"</div></td>"}else{if(r.getFullYear()==O.getFullYear()&&r.getMonth()>O.getMonth()){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+R+"' data-month='"+(O.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+O.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+R+"</div></td>"}}}V.append(U);R++}if(ad==x-1){var w="";var H="";if(f.getFullYear()==s.getFullYear()&&f.getMonth()==s.getMonth()&&f.getDate()==Y){w=" today-date ";H="data-title='"+z+"'"}if(i!=null&&i.getFullYear()==s.getFullYear()&&i.getMonth()==s.getMonth()&&i.getDate()==Y){w=" default-date ";H="data-title='"+ac+"'"}if(ab==0||ab==E-1){w+=" holiday "}if(typeof b.notes!=="undefined"){if(k(new Date(s.getFullYear(),s.getMonth(),Y))){w+=" note "}}var U="<td id='calendarClick' class='"+w+"' data-date='"+Y+"' data-month='"+(s.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+s.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+Y+"</div></td>";if(A!=null){if(A.getFullYear()<=s.getFullYear()){if(A.getMonth()<=s.getMonth()){if(A.getMonth()<s.getMonth()){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+Y+"' data-month='"+(s.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+s.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+Y+"</div></td>"}else{if(S<Y){U="<td class='"+w+"' data-date='"+Y+"' data-month='"+(s.getMonth()+1)+"' data-year='"+s.getFullYear()+"'><div class='entry' "+H+">"+Y+"</div></td>"}}}}}V.append(U);Y++}}}u.append(V)}var ai="";if(b.showNotes){var aa=m();var L=aa.length;if(L>0){ai=a("<ul class='dncalendar-note-list'></ul>");for(var ad=0;ad<L;ad++){var ae=aa[ad].date;var G=aa[ad].notes;var D=G.length;var I="";I+="<li class='date'>";I+="<span>"+ae+"</span> ";if(D>0){I+=" : ";for(var ab=0;ab<D;ab++){I+=G[ab];if(D<=ab){I+=", "}}}I+="</li>";ai.append(I)}}}P.append(q);P.append(u);C.append(P);l.html("");l.append(X);l.append(C);l.append(ai)};var k=function(p){var s=b.notes.length;for(var r=0;r<s;r++){var q=b.notes[r].date.split("-");var o=new Date(q[0],q[1]-1,q[2]);if(o.getFullYear()==p.getFullYear()&&o.getMonth()==p.getMonth()&&o.getDate()==p.getDate()){return true}}return false};var m=function(){var p=[];var t=b.notes.length;for(var s=0;s<t;s++){var r=b.notes[s].date.split("-");var o=new Date(r[0],r[1]-1,r[2]);if(o.getFullYear()==d.getFullYear()&&o.getMonth()==d.getMonth()){var q={};q.date=o.getDate();q.notes=b.notes[s].note;p.push(q)}}return p};var g=function(){var o=new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,1);var p=o.getDate();var r=o.getMonth();var q=o.getFullYear();d=new Date(q,r,p);h()};var c=function(){var q=new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()-1,1);var o=q.getDate();var r=q.getMonth();var p=q.getFullYear();d=new Date(p,r,o);h()};var j=function(){a("body").on("click","#calendarClick",function(){var o=a(this).data("date");var p=a(this).data("month");var q=a(this).data("year");b.dayClick.call(this,new Date(q,p-1,o),l)});a("body").on("click","#dncalendar-prev-month",function(){c()});a("body").on("click","#dncalendar-next-month",function(){g()})};return{build:function(){b=a.extend({},a.fn.dnCalendar.defaults,n);if(typeof b.defaultDate!=="undefined"){var o=b.defaultDate.split("-");d=new Date(o[0],o[1]-1,o[2]);i=d}h();j()},update:function(p){b=a.extend(b,p);if(typeof b.defaultDate!=="undefined"){var o=b.defaultDate.split("-");d=new Date(o[0],o[1]-1,o[2]);i=d}h()}}};a.fn.dnCalendar.defaults={monthNames:["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],monthNamesShort:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Agu","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dec"],dayNames:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],dayNamesShort:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],dayUseShortName:false,monthUseShortName:false,showNotes:false,dayClick:function(c,b){}}}(jQuery));
```

```css
.dncalendar-inactive{opacity:.2}.dncalendar-header{margin:20px 0;position:relative}.dncalendar-header h2{color:#fa8a20;font-size:20px;line-height:1;text-align:center}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links{height:19px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:2px}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links div{cursor:pointer;width:35px;height:35px;-webkit-user-select:none;touch-action:pan-y;-webkit-user-drag:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links .dncalendar-next-month{position:absolute;right:-6px;background:url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat -111px 0;background-size:148px 31px}.dncalendar-header .dncalendar-links .dncalendar-prev-month{position:absolute;left:10px;background:url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;background-size:148px 31px}.dncalendar-body{margin:0 0 10px}.dncalendar-body table{width:100%;text-align:center;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:15px}.dncalendar-body table th,td{display:table-cell;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}.dncalendar-body thead td{color:#727272;font-size:11px;text-transform:uppercase;padding:10px 0}.dncalendar-body tbody tr td{width:13%;border-top:1px solid #ddd;color:#bdbdbd;background:#f8f8f8;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:middle}.dncalendar-body tbody td#calendarClick{cursor:pointer}.dncalendar-body tbody td.calendarClick{color:#434343;background:#fff}.dncalendar-body tbody td .entry{padding:11px 0 13px;position:relative}.dncalendar-body tbody td.calendarClick:active{background:#ddd}.dncalendar-body tbody td .entry:after{content:attr(data-title);left:0;position:absolute;font-size:10px;bottom:1px;text-align:center;width:100%}.dncalendar-body table td.holiday{color:#fa8a20 !important}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.holiday{color:#fa8a20 !important}.dncalendar-body table td.default-date{border:1px solid #eee;color:#fff !important;background:#fa8a20}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.default-date{border:1px solid #ddd;color:#fff !important;background:#fa8a20}.dncalendar-body table td.today-date{border:1px solid #7ee699;color:#7ee699 !important;background:#e9fdee}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.today-date{border:1px solid rgba(100%,100%,100%,0.0);color:#fa8a20 !important;background:#ffecd9}.dncalendar-body table td.note,.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.note{position:relative}.dncalendar-body table td.note:before{display:block;position:absolute;width:0;height:0;top:0;right:0;content:"";border-top:5px solid #c55;border-right:5px solid #c55;border-left:5px solid transparent;border-bottom:5px solid transparent}.dncalendar-body table td.calendarClick.note:before{display:block;position:absolute;width:0;height:0;top:0;right:0;content:"";border-top:5px solid #d00;border-right:5px solid #d00;border-left:5px solid transparent;border-bottom:5px solid transparent}.dncalendar-note-list{list-style:none;margin-left:4.5%;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;color:#999}.dncalendar-note-list .date{color:#d00}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dncalendar-skin.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!---Calendar here --->
<div id="dncalendar-container"></div>
<!---End Calendar --->
<!---Modal here --->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!---End Modal --->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var my_calendar = $("#dncalendar-container").dnCalendar({
                dataTitles: { defaultDate: 'default', today : 'Today' },
                notes: [
                  { "date": "2016-02-25", "note": ["date here"] },
                  { "date": "2016-02-28", "note": ["date here"] }
                  ],
                showNotes: true,
                dayClick: function(date, view) {
                var selecteddate = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                 $('#myModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $('.modal-body').html(selecteddate);
       });
                }
   });

   // init calendar
   my_calendar.build();

   // update calendar
   my_calendar.update({
    minDate: "2016-02-23",
    defaultDate: new Date()
   });
  });
  </script>
```